# elasticsearch 6 index change to read only after few second

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to use elasticsearch 6 on mac os but when I create an index by adding a document to none exist index after few second index change to read-only and if add document or update document give this error

```
"error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "cluster_block_exception",
        "reason" : "blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/12/index read-only / allow delete (api)];"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "cluster_block_exception",
    "reason" : "blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/12/index read-only / allow delete (api)];"
  },
  "status" : 403
}
```

I test to disable read only by

```
curl -H'Content-Type: application/json' -XPUT localhost:9200/test/_settings?pretty -d'
{
    "index": {
        "blocks.read_only": false
    }
}'
{
  "acknowledged" : true
}
```

but nothing change

I test elastic 6  on another system with ubuntu os it's ok and there is no error then I think maybe something  wrong with my system but elasticsearch 5.6.2 works correctly without any error

the elastic log is

```
[2018-01-05T21:56:52,254][WARN ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [gCjouly] flood stage disk watermark [95%] exceeded on [gCjoulysTFy1DDU7f7dOWQ][gCjouly][/Users/peter/Downloads/elasticsearch-6.1.1/data/nodes/0] free: 15.7gb[3.3%], all indices on this node will marked read-only
```

Answer (score 41):

I had this problem
I think in elastic 6 add new setting to close index when empty hard less than 5% 
you can disable this by below line in elasticsearch.yml

```
 cluster.routing.allocation.disk.threshold_enabled: false
```

Then restart elasticsearch.
I hope this work for you

Comment: Yes thank you, finally!! I set this via the REST api as a [persistent setting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-update-settings.html) and now elasticsearch seems to obey.

Comment: For those on a Mac, `/usr/local/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml`

Answer (score 18):

Convenience for copy/pasting into Kibana console

```
# disable threshold alert
PUT /_cluster/settings
{
  "persistent" : {
        "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.threshold_enabled" : false
    }
}

# unlock indices from read-only state
PUT /_all/_settings
{
  "index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": null
}
```

Answer (score 13):

If you are working in with elastic search in Docker, it's possible that Docker has run out of space. Either run `docker volume prune` to remove unused local volumes or increase your disk image size in Docker Preferences.

Comment: This is a great finding, thanks for the contribution

Comment: What if the disk is already at the threshold after deleting the volumes also? This command is not recommended for production. We can do it in local.

Comment: This helped a ton! At least in my development environment.

Answer (score 4):

Run these commands

```
curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:9200/_cluster/settings -d '{ "transient": { "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.threshold_enabled": false } }'
curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:9200/_all/_settings -d '{"index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": null}'
```

If you are using docker containers then you wanted to make sure that you have enough space in your container and its usage should be less than 85%.

You can make up space by clear the dangling images and volumes by running the following commands

```
# remove the dangling images
docker rmi $(docker images -f "dangling=true" -q)

# remove the dangling volumes
docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -qf dangling=true)
```

If you still having space issues then better to increase the space for your docker by going into `Docker > Preferences`

[image]
[image]

**After making space for the docker, you need to run the above CURL command shared at the top of this post.**

Answer (score 0):

Its not recommended,

for a sudden debugging you can add below in docker,

```
elasticsearch:
 image: elasticsearch:7.9.3
 environment:
   "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.threshold_enabled": "false"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).